# How to listen on specific port on microservice using docker

Tags: java, docker, web-services, snmp, putty

I have a problem with listening on port on microservice using docker. Locally everything works perfect, so I am assuming there is only problem with proper configuration.

So I am starting to listening on microservice on the specific IP:PORT for the SNMP Messagess in such way:

```
    private static final String UDP = "udp:/";
    private static final String SLASH_PREFIX = "/";
    private static final String TRAP_IP = "0.0.0.0"; // or container-name

    private void prepareTrapConfiguration() throws IOException {
        MessageDispatcher dispatcher = getMessageDispatcher();

        Address listenAddress = GenericAddress.parse(String.format("%s%s%s%s", UDP, TRAP_IP, SLASH_PREFIX, 162));

        log.debug("Starting listening TRAP on: {} ", listenAddress.toString());
        DefaultUdpTransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping((UdpAddress) listenAddress);
        log.info("Started listening TRAP on: {} ", listenAddress.toString());

        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(dispatcher, transport);
        prepareSecurity(snmp);
        snmp.addCommandResponder(trapReceiverCmd);
        snmp.listen();
    }


    private void prepareSecurity(Snmp snmp) {
        snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv1());
        snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());


        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES());
    }
```

I am starting the docker image by docker-compose. Docker compose bellow:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
        
    snmp:
      image: snmp:latest
      container_name: snmp
      ports:
        - "5435:5435"
        - "127.0.0.1:162:162/udp"
      networks:
      - default
      restart: always


networks:
  default:
      driver: bridge
```

Afterthat I am tunnel the IP on the port 162. I have tried with SNMP container exactly IP, and also with localhost IP using putty.

[image: putty]

At the end I am sending message locally on the 127.0.0.1:162 and nothing happens - its not received on the container. By Wireshark I am receveing unapproachable port

thanks in advance for the tip

Comment: Am I correct - you are listening inside the container, and sending from localhost?

Comment: @AlexBuyny yes, sorry for not responding earlier

Answer (score 0):

If your host is Windows, try to listen to `host.docker.internal`, on linux - `172.17.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for response!! I don't want to make host on windows - I only would like to test my solution. It will be listening on centos - and the messages will not be from windows but from eg. switch devices.